# There are three instances of the application on the server. but we want to execute the cronjob schedular on one instance of the application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

There are three instances of the application on the server. but we want to execute the cronjob schedular logic on one instance of the application.
Using Spring-data, couchbase repository with couchbase database. is there any simple solution to my problem please suggest me.  thanks in advance . i suffer from this problem from many days.

Answer (score 1):

Facing similar situations with multiple spring boot instances, we schedule the cron externally, this can be a simple cron script that executes a curl, or a specific external scheduler app/instance. Your load balancer will pick an instance to run on.

You could also consider using quartz or shedlock with couchbase to manage without external trigger.